# Open clicked thumbnail in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code on one page:

```
<div id="prodoneid" class="prodcls">
    <a href="javascript:void(changeIt('big.png', 'pagewrapid')());">
        <img src="images/zara/thumbnails/1.png" alt="ZARA"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

By the below code I am opening the image in a new window. The new page is opening but is not showing the image in the div.

```
var changeIt, img;
changeIt = function(imageName, objName) { 
    img = '<img src="images/zara/' + imageName + '">';
    newwindow = window.open( 'fprod.html', target="_blank" );
    document.getElementById(objName).innerHTML = img;
    setTimeout('newwindow.document.getElementById("pagewrapid").innerHTML=img',0)
};
```

Comment: you need not raise a duplicate question. if you are not satisfied with answers, you can discuss in same thread.

Comment: dear raj if u see there only i have the last comments no one is solving the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any javascript for this, just add `target=_blank` to your `a` element:

```html
<div id="prodoneid" class="prodcls">
  <a href="images/zara/big.png" target="_blank">
    <img src="images/zara/thumbnails/1.png" alt="ZARA"/>
  </a>
</div>
```